# Sample data after using filter or select from sparkly

Tags: r, filter, sample, sparklyr

I have a large dataframe to analyse, so I'm using **sparklyr** to manage it in a fast way. My goal is to take a sample of the data, but before I need to select some variables of interest and filter some values of certain columns.
I tried to select and/or filter the data and then use the function sample_n but it always gives me this error:

> Error in vapply(dots(...), escape_expr, character(1)) :    values must
>   be length 1,  but FUN(X[[2]]) result is length 8

Below is an example of the behaviour:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc<-spark_connect(master='local')

data_example<-copy_to(sc,iris,'iris')

data_select<-select(data_example,Sepal_Length,Sepal_Width,Petal_Length)
data_sample<-sample_n(data_select,25)

data_sample
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, since I started using this package a few days ago, but I could not find any solution to this problem. Any help with be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a bug. In fact if you omit `select` it works :/ I'd open an [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues). Nevertheless you should really avoid exact samples. This is something that doesn't scale at all.

Comment: Thaks for the comment. I'll consider opening an issue to investigate this problem!

Comment: Thanks for the question. Tracking at https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/1299

Comment: Nice, I'll follow the issue... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed a problem with the type of object returned when you select/mutate/filter the data.
So, I managed to get around the problem by sending the data to spark using the compute() command, and then sampling the data.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc<-spark_connect(master='local')

data_example<-copy_to(sc,iris,'iris')

data_select<-data_example %>% 
  select(Sepal_Length,Sepal_Width,Petal_Length) %>% 
  compute('data_select')

data_sample<-sample_n(data_select,25)

data_sample
```

Unfortunatelly, this approach takes a long time to run and consumes a lot of memory, so I expect someday I'll find a better solution.

Comment: How about sdf_sample? This should work natively with sparklyr

Answer (score 0):

I had also get same issue earlier then I tried following:

```
data_sample = data_select %>% head(25)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in this case I wanted to take a sample of the data_select. Using the function `head` only shows me the first 25 elements without sampling it.